# Informix crashes with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when using ROW predicates in JOIN .. ON clauses

Tags: sql, informix

When running the following query on an Informix database, the database crashes fatally with an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

```sql
select 
  trim(systables.owner) owner,
  trim(systables.tabname) tabname,
  trim(sysconstraints.constrname) constrname,
  sysindexes.part1, sysindexes.part2,
  sysindexes.part3, sysindexes.part4,
  sysindexes.part5, sysindexes.part6,
  sysindexes.part7, sysindexes.part8,
  sysindexes.part9, sysindexes.part10,
  sysindexes.part11, sysindexes.part12,
  sysindexes.part13, sysindexes.part14,
  sysindexes.part15, sysindexes.part16
from
  sysconstraints 
    join systables 
      on sysconstraints.tabid = systables.tabid 
    join sysindexes 
      on row (sysconstraints.owner, sysconstraints.idxname) 
       = row (sysindexes.owner, sysindexes.idxname) 
order by
  sysconstraints.owner asc, 
  systables.tabname asc, 
  sysconstraints.constrname asc
```

The database I'm using is a Developer Edition of Informix 12.10 on Windows.

Comment: Also crashes 11.70 64bit workgroup edition (11.70.FC5GE) on Windows server 2008 r2, BUT works fine on 32bit edition on server 2003 (11.70.TC7GE). -Bryce.

Comment: @user1840734: Thanks for the additional info. The issue has also been reported on the [comp.databases.informix user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.informix/lbeyVeQKRA4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could track down the issue to be strictly related to the usage of `row()` predicates in the `join .. on` clause:

```
-- causes issues
from
  sysconstraints 
    join systables 
      on sysconstraints.tabid = systables.tabid 
    join sysindexes 
      on row (sysconstraints.owner, sysconstraints.idxname) 
       = row (sysindexes.owner, sysindexes.idxname)
```

Here's an equivalent `on` clause that works just fine:

```
-- causes no issues
from
  sysconstraints 
    join systables 
      on sysconstraints.tabid = systables.tabid 
    join sysindexes 
      on sysconstraints.owner = sysindexes.owner
     and sysconstraints.idxname = sysindexes.idxname
```

And here's an equivalent query that uses the `row()` predicates in the `where` clause, which also works:

```
-- causes no issues
from
  sysconstraints 
    join systables 
      on sysconstraints.tabid = systables.tabid 
    cross join sysindexes 
where row (sysconstraints.owner, sysconstraints.idxname) 
    = row (sysindexes.owner, sysindexes.idxname)
```

**Conclusion: do NOT use `ROW()` predicates in the Informix `JOIN .. ON` clause. It will crash your database**